# Is there an application to create windows with messages?

Tags: software-recommendation, scripts, zenity

I want to do something to create a window, preferably marked as on-top, with a configurable message.  Is there an Ubuntu package for that?

The idea to put the relevant command inside a script:

```
#!/bin/csh
docommand "hello world"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application you're looking for is called [zenity](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/zenity). Here's your hello world:

```
zenity --info --text="Hello World"
```

- [Documentation](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/)
- [Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/zenity.1.html)

Comment: There is also older xmessage. It is uglier, but has fewer dependencies.